# Can't get value of prop inside a callback when component is rendered until useEffect is placed in an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, closures, react-props, use-effect

I'm trying to use a callback method inside useEffect. The function of the callback is to 'do something' with the component's props but I can't get access to the props inside of the callback

For a little bit more context I'm using the animation library called gsap and I'm doing some scroll animations and I'm trying to use the callback method 'onEnter'. This method attaches an event listener to the scroll and runs some code when the element comes into view, pretty straight forward.

I'm integration this with a react app and I'm having some problems getting the callback function to get the values of the props, I can receive them inside useEffect but not the callback.

Here is my code:

```
const Services = ({loaded, scroller}) => {

   const [curSlide, setCurSlide] = useState(0);

   // Animate in text
   useEffect(() => {
    if (loaded) {
      // **** Scroll Animation and triggers for each slide ****
      sliders.forEach((slider, i) => {
        gsap.to(slider.title.current, {
          scrollTrigger: {
            //** HERE IS THE CALLBACK **//
            onEnter: () => {
              if (i === 0) return
              setCurSlide(i)
              console.log(scroller) // THIS RETURNS NULL WHEN SHOULD HAVE A VALUE
            }
          },
        });
      })
    }
  }, [loaded]) // Loaded only changes once

  return (
  <div>MAGICALLY WORK NOW?</div>
  );
}
```

The prop I'm specifically referring to is "scroller"

I'm hoping it's something stupid I'm doing wrong -  If I remove the usEffect I get access to the prop but I can't do that because it's causing a render loop, the same thing happens if I add curSlide to the useEffect Dependency Array. I don't understand why I get access to the prop after the component re-renders and not initially because the component should have access to it right away